# Can I replicate slaves without a dump?

Tags: mysql

I have setup a new slave in a set and I just want to allow it to naturally cach up to the master and start using the binary log once it has caught up.

However, I cannot seem to find anything on this, every method seems to require a pre-requisite dump of data. It would be a lot easier for me to just let the slave catch up naturally over a period of days.

Is there anyway I can do this or do I really have to take a full dump etc cetc?

Comment: How long has the master been running?

Comment: @ypercube a vey long time it has about 17GB of data, however, it does not receive a lot of OPs, the slave would have enough time to cach up

Comment: You have keep all the binlogs since MASTER started?

Comment: @Antonis no, binlog has only been recording for 2 weeks while master has been running year or two

Comment: In this case you can't

Comment: It makes me sad when somebody claims "No, you can't". That actually means "No, I don't know how".

Comment: I have a two-year-old post on how to do this with rsync : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21251/877

Comment: I also have this in ServerFault with Sample Code : http://serverfault.com/questions/288140/mysql-slave-replication-reset-with-no-master-downtime-using-myisam/288467#288467

Comment: If all your data is InnoDb, you are much better off doing a point-in-time dump with mysqldump or just going with the answer from @akuzminsky.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to create a slave either from the running master or slave.
Here Percona explains how to do it with XtraBackup http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/setting_up_replication.html#adding-more-slaves-to-the-master

You can use this procedure with slight variation to add new slaves to a master. We will use Percona XtraBackup to clone an already configured slave. We will continue using the previous scenario for convenience but we will add TheNewSlave to the plot.

At TheSlave, do a full backup:

```
TheSlave$ innobackupex --user=yourDBuser --password=MaGiCiGaM /
      --slave-info /path/to/backupdir
```

By using the --slave-info Percona XtraBackup creates additional file called xtrabackup_slave_info.

Apply the logs:

```
TheSlave$ innobackupex --apply-log --use-memory=2G /path/to/backupdir/$TIMESTAMP/
```

Copy the directory from the TheSlave to TheNewSlave (NOTE: Make sure mysqld is shut down on TheNewSlave before you copy the contents the snapshot into its datadir.):

rsync -avprP -e ssh /path/to/backupdir/$TIMESTAMP TheNewSlave:/path/to/mysql/datadir
Add additional grant on the master:

```
TheMaster|mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.*  TO 'repl'@'$newslaveip'
         IDENTIFIED BY '$slavepass';
```

Copy the configuration file from TheSlave:

```
TheNEWSlave$ scp user@TheSlave:/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Make sure you change the server-id variable in /etc/mysql/my.cnf to 3 and disable the replication on start:

```
skip-slave-start
server-id=3
```

After setting server_id, start mysqld.

Fetch the master_log_file and master_log_pos from the file xtrabackup_slave_info, execute the statement for setting up the master and the log file for The NEW Slave:

```
TheNEWSlave|mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO
               MASTER_HOST='$masterip',
               MASTER_USER='repl',
               MASTER_PASSWORD='$slavepass',
               MASTER_LOG_FILE='TheMaster-bin.000001',
               MASTER_LOG_POS=481;
```

and start the slave:

```
TheSlave|mysql> START SLAVE;
```

If both IO and SQL threads are running when you check the TheNewSlave, server is replicating TheMaster.

Comment: Sorry for not replying at the time, I was very busy. I did look into this solution but it was not truly being able to let a slave catch up, it still does a weighty backup, it merely uses INNODBs lock mechanics to not lock the database up. It is close but not there, also I heard it has problems with ISAM, and some of my older tables are still ISAM